# In Codeigniter 2.2.0 pagination menu without lists tags

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

In Codeigniter 2.2.0 I generate pagination menu and I see that elements from 2 till 4 are without ... tags:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li class="active">1</li>
  &nbsp;<a href="http://local-ci22.com/admin/hostel/index/page/2">2</a>
  &nbsp;<a href="http://local-ci22.com/admin/hostel/index/page/3">3</a>
  &nbsp;<a href="http://local-ci22.com/admin/hostel/index/page/4">4</a>
  <li class="next"><a href="http://local-ci22.com/admin/hostel/index/page/2">&gt;</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://local-ci22.com/admin/hostel/index/page/7">Last</a></li>
</ul>
```

In configuration file :

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = 'First';
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['last_link'] = 'Last';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['next_link'] = '&gt;';
$config['prev_link'] = '&lt;';
```

Which tags did I miss ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You missed the "Digit" link:

Copied from the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html) (changed from `div` to `li`, to fit your needs):

```
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
```

The opening tag for the "digit" link.

```
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

The closing tag for the "digit" link.